# Very strange error involving a simple substring

Tags: javascript, function, substring

I am trying to make a function which are supposed to check if a certain date is in the correct format. 
Do to this, the function takes in a variable, and breaks it down to three subvariables, year, month, and day. Later on I want to check each of these substrings against in a few if-statements.

When i run this with my GFs number which is 880413 then year=88, month=4, day=13
However, when I run this function with my own number which is 820922, then the function sets year to 82, month to 0?! and day=22.

How is this possibe? when month is 04, it cuts it off and shows only 4, but when month is 09 it cuts it off to 0.

Heres relevant code:

```
function isValidDate(date) 
{
    var valid = true;

    var year = parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));
    var month = parseInt(date.substring(2, 4)); // error here!
    var day = parseInt(date.substring(4, 6));
    alert(year+"--"+month+"--"+day+"--")
}
```

Heres output when running number 820922 (forget about the last 4 digits, they are for swedish social security number and do no need to be considered in this example)

[image]

And heres output with number 880413 (again forget about the last 4 digits)
[image]

Comment: `parseInt('09') // => 0`, but `parseInt('09', 10) // => 9`. If you don't provide the radix, the function assumes it's an octal value (since it starts with a zero), and as a result doesn't parse beyond the initial `0` (`9` is not an octal digit).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always specify a radix when using parseInt()

The reason for this is if you don't specify it, it doesn't default to base 10, instead it guesses based on the first digit/character. IE if it starts with a '0' then it is intepreted as octal

```
function isValidDate(date) 
{
    var valid = true;

    var year = parseInt(date.substring(0, 2), 10);
    var month = parseInt(date.substring(2, 4), 10);
    var day = parseInt(date.substring(4, 6), 10);
    alert(year+"--"+month+"--"+day+"--")
}
```

Or use `Number()` ie

```
var month = Number(date.substring(2, 4));
```

Comment: `Number()` doesn't take a second argument.

Comment: This seems to be working. Thanks for providning me with the correct answer and explaining to make things more clear! (cannot accept yet, will accept in 5 mins:) )

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Haha yeah sorry. That's what I get for copypasting and changing the function :)

Comment: @JimmyGustafsson No problem :) Douglas Crockford covers examples like this in his talks and books; Be sure to check those out :)

Answer (score 3):

Specify the base - use parseInt("09", 10). For legacy reasons, starting a number with a zero will be parsed as an octal. "8" and "9" are not valid octal digits, so "09" cannot be successfully parsed as an integer.

Edit - doing a bit of digging, and apparently what you did does fit the official ECMAscript standard, but most implementations use octal formatting anyway - details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_Interpretations_with_No_Radix).

Answer (score 1):

You will see the same problem in case of **08** also. This is because Javascript treats numbers starting with 0 as octal, and there is no `09` or `08` in octal. So you can provide the base as the 2nd parameter:

```
alert(parseInt('08',10));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you concatenate string with an integer it will never give you 04. To get the result that you want you need to use printf:

```
'%02d--%02d--%02d'.sprintf(year, month, day);
```

Function sprintf is from Prototype library.

Comment: The question is JavaScript... not Java. Unless you're suggesting the use of an external library?

Comment: Yeap I was thinking about Java, this question is tagged incorrectly. To remedy my mistake OP can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format/3932473#3932473).

Comment: He can't try your example, JavaScript does not offer a 'printf' function natively :(

Comment: Thanks for noticing it, I have modified my response.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression may help.

```
date.replace( /(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/,'$1--$2--$3--');
```